# Bad variable assigment in PYTHON

Tags: python, variables

Line 6 is a variable assigment and it does not work.... **why?**

I do not see the mistake

```
aleatorio = [11,2,5,9,3,4,8,13,7]
longitud = len(aleatorio)
contador = 0

for i in range(longitud-1):
  a = aleatorio[i]
  b = aleatorio[i + 1]
  print(a, b, i, i + 1)
  if a < b:
    contador = contador + 1 
  else:
    c = aleatorio[i]
    d = aleatorio[i+1]
    aleatorio[i] = d
    aleatorio[i+1] = c
print(aleatorio)
```

it prints:

```
11 2 0 1
11 5 1 2
11 9 2 3
11 3 3 4
11 4 4 5
11 8 5 6
11 13 6 7
13 7 7 8
[2, 5, 9, 3, 4, 8, 11, 7, 13]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do you think this code has a mistake?  The code is doing exactly what it's supposed to.  The 11 starts out in position 0, and keeps on moving to the right until it hits the 13.  The 13 then moves to the right until it hits the end.

Comment: What do you mean by line 6 (variable ```a``` right?) doesn't work, do you have an error message or something that tells you so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the list, you must make a small change like this:

```
aleatorio = [11,2,5,9,3,4,8,13,7]
longitud = len(aleatorio)


contador = 0
while contador!= longitud-1:
    contador=0
    for i in range(longitud-1):
        a = aleatorio[i]
        b = aleatorio[i + 1]
        print(a, b, i, i + 1)
        if a <= b:
            contador = contador + 1 
        else:
            c = aleatorio[i]
            d = aleatorio[i+1]
            aleatorio[i] = d
            aleatorio[i+1] = c
print(aleatorio)
```